# How not get out of bound in Kotlin?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I got the code that compare current element with the next element in array. But it crashes with out of bound because I guess when its on the last element there is no next element to compare with so it crashes.How to handle this to avoid crash and stop comparing on the last element? Here is my code

```
fun myFunction(arr: Array<Int>): Int{

        if (arr.isEmpty()) return 0
        var result = 0
        for (item in arr.indices) {
                if (arr[item] > 0 && arr[item + 1] < 0){
                    result ++
                }
                if (arr[item] < 0 && arr[item + 1] > 0){
                    result ++
                }
    }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: Check if `item` is less than array's length minus one first? Also, try multiplying the two items...

Comment: @tobias_k can you please provide example?

Comment: What do you expect `arr[item + 1]` to do when `item` is the last index in `arr`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The direct answer to your question:**

Instead of

```
for (item in arr.indices)
```

you should write

```
for (item in 0..(arr.lastIndex - 1))
```

Explanation: `arr.indices` returns the range `0..arr.lastIndex` but in the loop you are checking the element after the current index; therefore you should only go up to `arr.lastIndex - 1`.

**Some further advice:**

- `IntArray` is more efficient than `Array<Int>`
- You can combine the two `if` statements into one using the `||` (or) operator.
- If you are counting the number of sign changes, you need to consider how to interpret 0. In your code, an input of `[1,-1]` would give a result of 1 sign change, but `[1,0,-1]` would give 0, which seems wrong. To fix that, treat 0 as positive:

```
if ((arr[item] >= 0 && arr[item + 1] < 0) || arr[item] < 0 && arr[item + 1] >= 0) {
    result++
}
```

- You don't need to check if the array is empty; just remove that line. The loop won't be entered if the array is empty or if it has only 1 element.
- Finally, you can use some cool features of the standard libray (look them up in the documentation to learn them) which can make your function succinct:

```
fun myFunction(arr: IntArray): Int {
    var result = 0
    arr.asList().zipWithNext().forEach { (a, b) ->
    if ((a >= 0 && b < 0) || (a < 0 && b >= 0))
        result++
    }
    return result
}
```

and even more succinct still:

```
fun myFunction(arr: IntArray) =
    arr.asList().zipWithNext().count { (a, b) -> (a >= 0) != (b >= 0) }
```

References: [single-expression functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions), [zipWithNext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html), [count](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html), [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html#destructuring-in-lambdas).

Comment: `for (item in 0 until arr.lastIndex)` means the same as `for (item in 0..(arr.lastIndex - 1))`, and is arguably easier to read. ([`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) is like `..` except that it excludes the end element.) But yes, as you show, there are simpler approaches.

Comment: @gidds I chose not to use `until` because in this case it doesn't have the immediate appearance of wanting to go to the _last but one_ element, whereas `lastIndex - 1` is explicit and more obvious. There are other legitimate uses of `until` (such as `until arr.size`).

Comment: Fair enough. The omission of the last element is indeed worth making clear to the reader, and perhaps the `..` version does do that. (If that were the main part of the answer, it might still be worth mentioning `until` for folks who aren't aware of it — but it's not, and the answer is full enough already!)